# Проблема с SQL запросом (Неожиданный токен, Неизвестный оператор)

Tags: sql

Ребята, понимаю что вопрос детский, но не могу понять, в чем проблема с этим простейшим SQL запросом

INSERT INTO users(image) VALUES ('somevalue') WHERE email = 'cz@cz.cz'

Задача, вставить в таблицу users, в столбец image значение somevalue в ту строку, где поле email равняется значению cz@cz.cz

MySQL версия 5.6, локальная машина. Строка со значением email равному cz@cz.cz есть

Получаю ошибку:
Ошибка
Статический анализ:
Найдено 2 ошибок при анализе.
    Неожиданный токен. (near "WHERE" at position 46)
    Неизвестный оператор. (near "WHERE" at position 46)
SQL запрос:
INSERT INTO users(image) VALUES ('somevalue') WHERE email = 'cz@cz.cz'
Ответ MySQL: Документация

## 1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'WHERE email = 'cz@cz.cz'' на строке 1

Благодарю!

Comment: Попробуйте всё же почитать справку. В частности, найти WHERE clause в запросе `INSERT .. VALUES` - не найдёте. Он допустим только в `INSERT .. SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу сам себе. Пользуйтесь оператором UPDATE, если хотите что-то вставить в уже существующее поле, пусть и пустое.